# Slide Toogle присваивает значение inline-block

Tags: jquery, css

Есть вот такой вот блок:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Configure/customize these variables.
  var showChar = 200; // How many characters are shown by default
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Подробнее";
  var lesstext = "Свернуть";


  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span><a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });

  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().slideToggle(200);
    $(this).prev().slideToggle(200);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

.morelink {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more">
  Morbi placerat imperdiet risus quis blandit. Ut lobortis elit luctus, feugiat erat vitae, interdum diam. Nam sit amet arcu vitae justo lacinia ultricies nec eget tellus. Curabitur id sapien massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst. Integer
  tristique leo consectetur libero pretium pretium. Nunc sed mauris magna. Praesent varius purus id turpis iaculis iaculis. Nulla <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. Donec et feugiat sem, ac rhoncus mauris. Quisque eget tempor massa.
</div>
```

При разворачивании блоку `.morecontent span` присваивается свойство `inline-block`, а нужно просто `inline`. Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Воспользоваться коллбэком и впилить блоку `display: inline`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Configure/customize these variables.
  var showChar = 200; // How many characters are shown by default
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Подробнее";
  var lesstext = "Свернуть";


  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span><a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });

  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().slideToggle(200);
    $(this).prev().slideToggle(200, function () {
      if ( $(this).is(':visible') ) $(this).css('display', 'inline');
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

.morelink {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more">
  Morbi placerat imperdiet risus quis blandit. Ut lobortis elit luctus, feugiat erat vitae, interdum diam. Nam sit amet arcu vitae justo lacinia ultricies nec eget tellus. Curabitur id sapien massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst. Integer
  tristique leo consectetur libero pretium pretium. Nunc sed mauris magna. Praesent varius purus id turpis iaculis iaculis. Nulla <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. Donec et feugiat sem, ac rhoncus mauris. Quisque eget tempor massa.
</div>
```